# Backbone view events binding on view's element

Tags: backbone.js

I have view with states represented by class (ex. state: .inserting-element) on the view's element. I have run into problem when binding events, the following won't work:

```js
events: {
  'mouseenter .inserting-element .list-item': function...
}
```

because the selector expects that .inserting-element is defined on some descendant of this.el (which is one possible solution - have an extra wrapper to represent the state). I have posted my current solution as answer but I wonder if there is some pure 'selector' way?

Comment: The binding exists in the `el` element itself, and the selector will be resolved with the `el` as the context. So your selector is supposed to be *inside* the `el`. Your current solution seems to be doing the job. else just and a *dummy* container `<div>` inside the views template and add the classes to it...

Comment: So you are saying that inserting-element is outside of the View? I think its a good thing Backbone view events are locked in, this is very strong and modular. I would not suggest having parent states defined in your view, to keep it a single component. A wrapper view would be a good way to go.

Comment: @LaurensKling no the 'state class' is on the view element itself.. not outside of course! But then the selector won't work - that was main purpose of my question - if there is a way to 'select' the view's element itself somehow.

Comment: @TJ yep, I know. I was just curious if there is a way..

Comment: aaah you want to check a class on the `el` itself. Hm. I know i've done some events on the `el` before, but not with their children. So i think you do might need to set the event yourself in the initialize. But you can still scope it within your `el` at that point, not make it global. jQuery has ways for that.

Answer (score 0):

The (current) solution is to test the state inside handler:

```js
events: {
  'mouseenter .list-item': function (event) {
    if ( this.$el.is('.inserting-element') ) {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: with this, you are making global events, something you can, and should, avoid with Backbone. Try keeping events within your views and make nested views.

Comment: no global events at all.. only events that are bounded to the view element

Comment: If you run this code, all mouseenter's on .list-item are triggered, you only use it in the if, but still you've registered the event globally.

Comment: I would suggest something like: 
    $( this.el ).on( "mouseenter", ".list-item", function() {
         ...
    });

Comment: Maybe you did't understand that the code snippet is member of backbone view 'events' object (I have edited it to be clear) and therefore bounded to view's this.el only

Comment: @LaurensKling - backbone actually does something similar you have suggested internally when view instance is created or setElement or delegateEvents are called

Comment: Ah yes, this is what i ment :)